# How to extract string ="1xxxx , 11xxxx, 21xxxx" into array[{objecta:1xxxx,objectb:11xxxx,objectc:21xxxx}]

Tags: excel, vba

How to extract `string ="1xxxx , 11xxxx, 21xxxx"`  into `array[{objecta:1xxxx,objectb:11xxxx,objectc:21xxxx}]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Would you just like an Array? Then you can use

```vb
Array("1xxxx", "11xxxx", "21xxxx")
```

Or

```vb
Split("1xxxx,11xxxx,21xxxx", ",")
```

Comment: Array("1xxxx", "11xxxx", "21xxxx") like this also can